# Draw transformed image with WebGL

Tags: javascript, opengl, html5-canvas, webgl, node-modules

I'm trying to draw a transformed image using WebGL and some [StackGL](http://stack.gl/) modules. I have a loaded image and its `mat3` transform. Shaders and texture are ready to use.

The code below draws a stretched image which has the same dimensions as the canvas. It does not apply the Matrix transformation. I think the image is stretched because of the buffer vertices.

I have tired to apply the Matrix transformation using a [code snipped found in the Pixi.js](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/blob/dev/src/core/renderers/webgl/shaders/TextureShader.js#L61) renderer, but then, nothing was rendered (and no error was thrown):

```
gl_Position = vec4((uTransform * vec3(aPosition, 1.0)).xy, 0.0, 1.0);
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I draw this image with it's original width/height?
2. How can I apply the matrix transformation to the image?
3. Can somebody post here a code snipped for displaing a simple image on the canvas, even without those transformations?

I have not found any tutorial that simply shows how to draw a texture (not on a ... spinning cube or a triangular-based pyramid) with it's original width/height.

---

**Fragment shader:**

```
precision lowp float;

varying vec2      vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTextureCoord);
}
```

**Vertex shader:**

```
precision lowp float;

varying   vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform   mat3 uTransform;
attribute vec2 aPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position   = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aPosition;
}
```

**Example of matrix values:**

```
[0.9950041770935059, 0.0998334139585495, 0, -0.0998334139585495, 0.9950041770935059, 0, -5.846673488616943, -24.447290420532227, 1]
[0.646919310092926, 0.7625584602355957, 0, -0.7625584602355957, 0.646919310092926, 0, 61.47933578491211, -42.35515594482422, 1]
```

This matrix transform works well with the `Canvas2d API`, `setTransform()`: it rotates, scales and moves the image as I want.

**Javascript code:**

```
var shader  = require( "gl-shader" );
var buffer  = require( "gl-buffer" );
var texture = require( "gl-texture2d" );

var SpriteRenderer = function ( context ) {
    this.gl = context;

    this.vert = require( "./shaders/vert.js" );
    this.frag = require( "./shaders/frag.js" );

    this.shader = shader( this.gl, this.vert, this.frag );
    this.buffer = buffer( this.gl, [ -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  1.0 ] );

    this.texture = texture( this.gl, window.TEST_SPRITE );
};

SpriteRenderer.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        this.shader.attributes.aPosition.location = 0;
    },

    render: function ( sprite ) {
        this.buffer.bind();
        this.shader.bind();

        this.shader.uniforms.uTexture   = this.texture.bind();
        this.shader.uniforms.uTransform = sprite.transform.array;

        this.shader.attributes.aPosition.pointer();

        this.gl.drawArrays( this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
    }
};
```

Comment: The result will totally depend on the projection matrix you use. However, you also do not correctly apply the projection matrix, at least if you want a perspective effect. YOur vertex shader also does not write to `vTextureCoord`.

Comment: @derhass I have updated the question. I don't really want a perspective effect (I should name the variable `uTransformation`, not `uProjection`, my fault).

Comment: [Does this help](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html)?